# Shared library not linking / cannot be done this way?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

Here's my issue:
In my project, I have a class called `Match`. Now, I would like to use somebody else's code to compare their results. They, unfortunately, also have a class called `Match`.

OK, so I thought I'd do:

```
namespace MonteCarlo {
#include "monte-carlo/match.hpp"
}
```

I appreciate that this is not best practice, but I really just want to test the output for now rather than rewrite everything in new namespaces.

Then, I made a shared library out of his code, and linked it:

```
LIBPATHS = -L mysql_connector/lib/ -Lmonte-carlo/lib                                                                                                                                                                                           
LIBS = -l mysqlcppconn -l boost_date_time -l boost_iostream  boost_system -l boost_filesystem -l MonteCarloTennis
```

But when I build, I get:

```
evaluator.cc:139: undefined reference to `MonteCarlo::Match::Match(double, double, double, double, bool, bool)'
evaluator.cc:140: undefined reference to `MonteCarlo::Match::play_match()'
```

But in the library, using nm, I see:

```
0000000000001286 T Match::Match(double, double, double, double, bool, bool)
0000000000001286 T Match::Match(double, double, double, double, bool, bool)
```

I am really new to libraries, so I could really use your advice. Am I getting this linker error because my library is not linking correctly, or because I wrapped the Match class in the namespace and thus the two functions in the library are not found?

Comment: No you can't locally put the external symbols in another namespace, as the namespace name will be part of the symbol names the compiler and linker will try to look up.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! I'll see if I can work around that. There were a lot of things that I could have got wrong, so it's good to know it's probably this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Joachim Pileborg for providing the answer!

Wrapping the `#include` in a namespace meant the linker couldn't find the corresponding function in the library. I have now fixed the issue by putting my colleague's code into namespaces.

So a very simple error, but there was so much that could have gone wrong (my first time building a library!) that it was really helpful to get Joachim's advice. Thanks again!